# How to check if Place is near to My driving route in GeoDjango

Tags: python, django, routes, spatial, geodjango

I want to check weather a given location (**Point of Interest**) is in the certain range of my Driving Route(**LineString**). I guess bbcontains, bboverlaps are the options but not sure since there are no video tutorials of **GeoDjango**.
Leaving useful link below if someone can help me out here.

[bbcontains&bboverlaps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#bboverlaps)

I seen some where that an envelope can be drawn around a linestring but now unable to get the link on internet. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

Ans is distance function in GeoDjango Queries.